# In Google Maps API, how do you access Map class methods or MapOptions properties of your map when you don't have direct access to the your Map object?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

**I don't have direct access to my Map object.** I am gaining access of the Map object by calling the first child of the div that carries it, that is, the 0th child. This JavaScript works:

```
var map = $('#mapdiv');
google.maps.event.trigger(map[0], 'resize');
```

I want to do something like this:

```
var map = $('#mapdiv');
var center = map[0].getCenter();
map[0].setCenter(center);
```

The code above doesn't work.

[image: javascript console]

Is there any way to access getCenter() and setCenter() when I don't have direct access to the Map object but only the div which carries my Map object?

Comment: how exactly are you initializing the map?

Comment: I am initializing the map inside a method which actually creates many maps on the page (one for each database entry). Each map is not displayed on the page until the user clicks a click listener.

Comment: your positive that the first bit of JS works? because if that works I see no reason why the second part should be throwing an error unless it truly does not have a getCenter method which it clearly does.

Comment: @stewbydoo more details: When the user finally clicks the "click listener", the maps shows up with a grey area and is off-center. So I need to run this setCenter method to fix that. But my map object is only local to the method it was originally generated in (that method is the one which creates each map on the page). So I don't have access to that object outside that method.

Comment: @stewbydoo Yes, I'm positive it works because when I simply run that line of code in the "click listener", it fixes the grey area from showing up and there are no errors in my console.

Comment: Perhaps you could help us to help you by posting more code (or a jsfiddle that exhibits the problem)

Comment: I am skeptical to post more code because it is very personal to my company but I do have an idea that I would like to bounce off you guys. Do you think that map[0] is actually not the Map object? I know it should be a Map object because google.maps.event.trigger(map[0], 'resize'); worked just fine. But maybe google.maps.event.trigger(map[0], 'resize'); is just smart enough to digest map[0]. I other words, I think map[0] is just some sort of html div. google.maps.event.trigger(map[0], 'resize'); knows to dig deeper than map[0] when you use it but getCenter() does not. What do you guys think?

Comment: map[0] is a div-node as the error-message says. `google.maps.event.trigger` works also with DOM-elements, but there is no way to get a pointer to a Map-object from the element that contains the map(except you implement it on your own, e.g. by storing a reference to the map as a property of the div)

Comment: @Dr.Molle Thank you as your comment led me to a solution. I ended up deciding to create my Map object in the place where I was trying to gain reference to it. So the problem ended up switching to trying to gain reference to lat and lon data rather than the object itself. And for that, I just sent the data into the div as attributes which can be accessed by JQuery functions.